# Real location of jquery in rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, asset-pipeline

One day I've got jquery.js file corrupted (maybe because of my IDE, i don't really know), it has arbitrary number in the beginning. I can see this in the browser:

```
3/*!
 * jQuery JavaScript Library v1.6.2
 * http://jquery.com/
 *
 *
```

I'm under Rails 3.1, using Pipeline by default. So I've checked the places which Pipeline can retrieve **jquery**. The first was vendor/assets/javascripts project's directory, it was empty.
Then I went to location where gem **jquery-rails** is located `/home/megas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails31/gems/jquery-rails-1.0.14/vendor/assets/javascripts/` but all files there are OK.

Where I can find real jquery file?

Comment: Some other file your application is requesting is probably generating this number.

Comment: good hint but how to understand where this generating happening?

Comment: Look at the order of includes and check if there is anything like this at your application.js file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find what was the problem, so I had to recreate project and this bug went way.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked `/usr/share/javascript` ?

Comment: Now I've checked this folder and js files are OK.